# Update record in database using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi there Iam using codeIgniter and I have managed to simply post a id number and phone number into the a table named "offers" both fields are INT, however when i try update a phone number corresponding to a specific id I see no changes in the database. I have listed my controller , model and view below

**newOffer controller**

```
   <?php 
    if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
  //insert data into db using offer_model model
  // other option update submit 
  class newOffer extends CI_Controller {
       function addOffer() {
       //if the form is submitted           
       $this->load->view("check");
       $this->load->model("offer_model");
         if ($this->input->post('mysubmit')) {
             $this->offer_model->entry_insert();
          }
       }

        function updateOffer (){
           $this->load->view("check2");
           $this->load->model("offer_model");
           if ($this->input->post('mysubmit')) {
                $this->offer_model->upddata();
            }
         }
    }
  ?>
```

**offer_model**

```
class offer_model extends CI_Model{

 public function entry_insert(){
      $data = array(
           'idNum' => $this->input->post('idNum'),
            'phneNum' => $this->input->post('phneNum'),

        );
      $this->db->insert('offers',$data);
  }

   public function upddata($data) {
    $this->db->where('idNum', $idNum);
    $this->db->update('data' ,$data);
    //extract($data); 
  //$data['OfferName']
  //$this->db->where('OfferName' ,  $data['OfferName']); 
    //$this->db->update($Offers, array('OfferName' => $OfferName)); 
   return true;
    }
}
 ?>
```

**The view to update the values**

```
<?form _open(base_url()."index.php/newOffer/updateOffer")?>
<div class="form">
 // <?php echo form_open('newOffer/addOffer'); ?>
<legend>Please enter details for your new offer</legend>
<label for="ID Number">ID Number:  <span class="required">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="idNum" id="idNum" placeholder="Please enter ID Number/>
<label for="phone Number">Phone Number:</label>
<input type="text" name="phneNum" id="phneNum " placeholder="Please enter phone Number"/>

 <fieldset class="submit_field">
     <?php echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Submit Form'); ?>
 </fieldset>
 </div><!-- end of form div -->
   ?>
```

Comment: $idNum is not a variable in the scope of the model function upddata

Answer (score 1):

You aren't passing any data to your model here

```
$this->offer_model->upddata();
```

You need to add something like

```
$this->offer_model->upddata($this->input->post());
```

Also in your Model code `$idNum` is undefined you will need to provide that too.

e.g:

```
public function upddata($data) {
  $idNum = $data['idNum'];
  unset($data['idNum']);
  $this->db->where('idNum', $idNum);
  $this->db->update('offers' ,$data);
  return true;
}
//etc
```

Comment: `$idNum` is also undefined.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I was just getting to that thanks: see my comment to the question above

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are feting from the same table in which you are inserting or updating data.

```
public function upload($id_akun, $data)
    {
        $table = "foto";

        $this->db->where("id_akun", $data['id_akun']);
        $count = $this->db->count_all_results($table);


        if ($count < 1) {
            $this->db->insert($table, $data);
        } else {
            $this->db->where('id_akun', $data['id_akun']);
            $this->db->update($table, $data);
        }
    }
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Use construct for load your model in controller And always pass the post data to the model function then only you will find the form post data into model function.

```
<?php 
  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

  function __construct()
  {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("offer_model");
  }

  class newOffer extends CI_Controller {
       function addOffer() {
       //if the form is submitted           
       $this->load->view("check");
       $this->load->model("offer_model");
         if ($this->input->post('mysubmit')) {
             $CI_Post = $$this->input->post();
             $this->offer_model->entry_insert($CI_Post);
          }
       }

        function updateOffer (){
           $this->load->view("check2");

           if ($this->input->post('mysubmit')) {
              $CI_Post = $$this->input->post();
              $this->offer_model->upddata($CI_Post);
           }
         }
    }
?>
```

Here is model which getting form post data in array.

```
<?php
class offer_model extends CI_Model{

     public function entry_insert($param=""){
          $data = array(
               'idNum' => $param['idNum'],
                'phneNum' => $param['phneNum'],

            );
          $this->db->insert('offers',$data);
          return $this->db->insert_id();
      }

     public function upddata($param="") {
      $data = array(
             'idNum' => $param['idNum'],
              'phneNum' => $param['phneNum'],

      );
      $this->db->where('idNum', $idNum);
      $this->db->update('data' ,$data);
      return $this->db->affected_rows();
     }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

in your model do something like

```
public function upddata() {
    $data=array();
    $data=$this->input->post(); //get all post value to data array
    $idNum=$data['idNum'];
    unset($data['idNum']); // unset unnecessary values 
    $this->db->where('idNum', $idNum)->update('offers' ,$data);
    return true;
}
```

this is the procedure.If you have 100 input fields then its not possible to add every value to an array. Please let me know if you face any problem.

**update**

change

```
<?php echo form_open('newOffer/addOffer'); ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo form_open('newOffer/updateOffer'); ?>
```

in The view to update the values

Comment: Its better to retrieve form data in the controller then pass to the model. Why pass data as a parameter and then erase it, then poulate it. Breaks the MVC pattern a bit IMO

Comment: It can be done in controller too but it's not breaking the MVC structure.

Comment: I disagree.What if you want to update the row, but not via post? Also what is the point of $data as a function parameter in your example?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096632/codeigniter-best-practice-in-accessing-this-input-post

Comment: yes its saying.....first sample: flexible and the second sample: 'd*mnit, not again!'....both are correct.so you shouldn't down voted for that.

Comment: I have adjusted my updata() function like u advised  however it seems to add instead of update. I would like for example to update a phone number where Id is 1  @Aborty

Comment: I didn't downvote. Your model function would probably work. I think it breaks the pattern because you have tied your model function to post. If you can't see that I don't know what to say.

Comment: @user2307970 it will update the row where id is 1.no problem.just use the code.

Comment: @ABorty perhaps its something to do with my submit                                                                          <fieldset class="submit_field">
                <?php echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Submit Form'); ?>
            </fieldset>